# How much of NVS Data can we really use in ESP32?

Tags: partitioning, freertos, flash-memory, esp32, non-volatile

I'm checking my NVS storage capacity. This is my output when i do make partition.

```
toolchain path: /home/dhananjay/esp/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc
Toolchain version: crosstool-ng-1.22.0-80-g6c4433a
```

Compiler version: 5.2.0
`Python requirements from /home/dhananjay/esp/esp-idf/requirements.txt` are satisfied.
Partition table binary generated. Contents:

---

```
# Espressif ESP32 Partition Table
# Name, Type, SubType, Offset, Size, Flags

nvs,data,nvs,0x9000,16K,
otadata,data,ota,0xd000,8K,
phy_init,data,phy,0xf000,4K,
factory,app,factory,0x10000,1M,
ota_0,app,ota_0,0x110000,1M,
ota_1,app,ota_1,0x210000,1M,
*******************************************************************************
Partition flashing command:
python /home/dhananjay/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip esp32 --port /dev/ttyUSB1 --baud 115200 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash 0x8000 /home/dhananjay/esp/Homebridge/build/partitions_two_ota.bin
dhananjay
```

Which shows that i can use 16k of nvs storage, yet when i write into nvs through namespace "storage" and keys "a"-"p" with each key containing 1022 bytes of data.
i get this output.

```
Done
String written successfully
Namespace a Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace b Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace c Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace d Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace e Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace f Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace g Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace h Completed
Done
String written successfully
Namespace i Completed
Done
Not enough Storage space
Wrongfull termination in Writing String
```

i Can only store 10220 Kb of data please help.

Comment: With a custom partition table, and maybe with some minimal/trivial SDK patching, you could probably hugely increase the amount of 16kB, if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

The 16KB is the amount of (hardware) storage. The NVS library has some overhead, though. You can see what all is consuming the storage by using the nvs_get_stats() command, documented on this page:

[ESP32 NVS Library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/storage/nvs_flash.html#api-reference)

You can experiment by erasing the partition, then running a loop that adds an entry, then calls the nvs_get_stats() routine.

Answer (score 2):

One other thing to note: WIFI makes extensive use of the 'nvs' partition. I just dumped the nvs partition on a couple of boards (one had been in use, the other was 'virgin'), and found about HALF of the 16KB was used by WIFI.

I'm guessing about the data, but judging from a hex dump (below), it appears STA (client) data, AP (Access Point) data, and phy cal data was being stored there. They shouldn't NEED to store all this stuff (my app only EVER works in STA mode, and all the required parameters are hard coded in the firmware.

Also NOTE: the current (as of 2019.10.25) ESP-IDF & example code will 're-init' the nvs partition if it runs out of 'free' pages, OR discovers the format is different than the current code (in my case the bootloader use older code, and I suspect a recent app build incorporated newer code that updated the nvs format). The re-init does not appear to PRESERVE nvs contents, so DON'T expect your 'non-volatile' data to exist if you keep re-writing your flash partition.

One solution to this issue is to use a flash file system partion (such as SPIFFS) instead.

My solution is to ignore the default 'nvs' partition, and create a custom partition of 'nvs' type, to store my non-volatile data, such as described in [this article](https://medium.com/the-esp-journal/building-products-creating-unique-factory-data-images-3f642832a7a3)

More info on the contents & use of partitions is available in the [API Guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/partition-tables.html)

'nvs' partition:

```
00000000: fcff ffff 0000 0000 feff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000010: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff 842d bab9  .............-..
00000020: aaaa 0aa8 aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa  ................
00000030: 0aa8 aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aafa  ................
00000040: 0001 01ff 5f2b 2470 6d69 7363 0000 0000  ...._+$pmisc....
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 01ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000060: 0142 0200 7476 e997 6c6f 6700 0000 0000  .B..tv..log.....
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0400 ffff 7437 f655  ............t7.U
00000080: 0200 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000090: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000a0: 0148 01ff 27e9 e5d2 6c6f 6700 0000 0000  .H..'...log.....
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0400 0000 0100 ffff  ................
000000c0: 0001 01ff 92d4 208a 6e76 732e 6e65 7438  ...... .nvs.net8
000000d0: 3032 3131 0000 0000 02ff ffff ffff ffff  0211............
000000e0: 0201 01ff f902 e2df 6f70 6d6f 6465 0000  ........opmode..
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 02ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000100: 0242 0300 9489 8e0b 7374 612e 7373 6964  .B......sta.ssid
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2400 ffff 734c d08c  ........$...sL..
00000120: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000130: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000140: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000150: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000160: 0248 01ff 0ce6 3d50 7374 612e 7373 6964  .H....=Psta.ssid
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2400 0000 0100 ffff  ........$.......
00000180: 0242 0200 3788 3252 7374 612e 6d61 6300  .B..7.2Rsta.mac.
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff 5cb3 e40f  ............\...
000001a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000001b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000001c0: 0248 01ff d0eb ce67 7374 612e 6d61 6300  .H.....gsta.mac.
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0100 ffff  ................
000001e0: 0201 01ff 2e92 65d4 7374 612e 6175 7468  ......e.sta.auth
000001f0: 6d6f 6465 0000 0000 01ff ffff ffff ffff  mode............
00000200: 0242 0400 dffa a1fa 7374 612e 7073 7764  .B......sta.pswd
00000210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4100 ffff 9d33 8936  ........A....3.6
00000220: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000230: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000240: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000250: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000260: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000270: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000280: 0248 01ff 884b 1150 7374 612e 7073 7764  .H...K.Psta.pswd
00000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4100 0000 0100 ffff  ........A.......
000002a0: 0242 0200 a398 6553 7374 612e 706d 6b00  .B....eSsta.pmk.
000002b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 ffff 5901 9919  ........ ...Y...
000002c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000002d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000002e0: 0248 01ff e293 d8f9 7374 612e 706d 6b00  .H......sta.pmk.
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 0000 0100 ffff  ........ .......
00000300: 0201 01ff 21e5 153b 7374 612e 6368 616e  ....!..;sta.chan
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000320: 0201 01ff 859b 696a 6175 746f 2e63 6f6e  ......ijauto.con
00000330: 6e00 0000 0000 0000 01ff ffff ffff ffff  n...............
00000340: 0201 01ff 4ab2 790d 6273 7369 642e 7365  ....J.y.bssid.se
00000350: 7400 0000 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  t...............
00000360: 0242 0200 268b db98 7374 612e 6273 7369  .B..&...sta.bssi
00000370: 6400 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff 5cb3 e40f  d...........\...
00000380: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000390: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000003a0: 0248 01ff c1e8 27ad 7374 612e 6273 7369  .H....'.sta.bssi
000003b0: 6400 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0100 ffff  d...............
000003c0: 0202 01ff 4747 fae1 7374 612e 6c69 735f  ....GG..sta.lis_
000003d0: 696e 7476 616c 0000 0300 ffff ffff ffff  intval..........
000003e0: 0201 01ff bdad 9d90 7374 612e 7068 796d  ........sta.phym
000003f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 03ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000400: 0201 01ff 9ad5 2ab8 7374 612e 7068 7962  ......*.sta.phyb
00000410: 7700 0000 0000 0000 02ff ffff ffff ffff  w...............
00000420: 0242 0200 dd79 1eb7 7374 612e 6170 7377  .B...y..sta.apsw
00000430: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0200 ffff 00ed d941  ...............A
00000440: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000450: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000460: 0248 01ff b38d 979e 7374 612e 6170 7377  .H......sta.apsw
00000470: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0200 0000 0100 ffff  ................
00000480: 0242 1700 a2e1 fc37 7374 612e 6170 696e  .B.....7sta.apin
00000490: 666f 0000 0000 0000 bc02 ffff 5754 b5a4  fo..........WT..
000004a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000004b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000004c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000004d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000004e0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000004f0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000500: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000510: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000520: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000530: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000540: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000550: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000560: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000570: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000580: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000590: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005e0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000005f0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000600: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000610: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000620: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000630: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000640: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000650: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000660: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000670: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000680: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000690: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006e0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000006f0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000700: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000710: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000720: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000730: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000740: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000750: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000760: 0248 01ff 25be d3fc 7374 612e 6170 696e  .H..%...sta.apin
00000770: 666f 0000 0000 0000 bc02 0000 0100 ffff  fo..............
00000780: 0201 01ff cd66 eace 7374 612e 7363 616e  .....f..sta.scan
00000790: 5f6d 6574 686f 6400 00ff ffff ffff ffff  _method.........
000007a0: 0201 01ff f4b1 7bcf 7374 612e 736f 7274  ......{.sta.sort
000007b0: 5f6d 6574 686f 6400 00ff ffff ffff ffff  _method.........
000007c0: 0211 01ff 1c92 d883 7374 612e 6d69 6e72  ........sta.minr
000007d0: 7373 6900 0000 0000 81ff ffff ffff ffff  ssi.............
000007e0: 0201 01ff 7cf9 6953 7374 612e 6d69 6e61  ....|.iSsta.mina
000007f0: 7574 6800 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  uth.............
00000800: 0242 0300 a8ee 9331 6170 2e73 7369 6400  .B.....1ap.ssid.
00000810: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2400 ffff 734c d08c  ........$...sL..
00000820: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000830: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000840: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000850: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000860: 0248 01ff 3081 206a 6170 2e73 7369 6400  .H..0. jap.ssid.
00000870: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2400 0000 0100 ffff  ........$.......
00000880: 0242 0200 2b40 dac7 6170 2e6d 6163 0000  .B..+@..ap.mac..
00000890: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff 5cb3 e40f  ............\...
000008a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000008b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000008c0: 0248 01ff cc23 26f2 6170 2e6d 6163 0000  .H...#&.ap.mac..
000008d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0100 ffff  ................
000008e0: 0242 0400 c8c4 0101 6170 2e70 6173 7377  .B......ap.passw
000008f0: 6400 0000 0000 0000 4100 ffff 9d33 8936  d.......A....3.6
00000900: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000910: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000920: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000930: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000940: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000950: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000960: 0248 01ff 9f75 b1ab 6170 2e70 6173 7377  .H...u..ap.passw
00000970: 6400 0000 0000 0000 4100 0000 0100 ffff  d.......A.......
00000980: 0242 0200 8dff 205e 6170 2e70 6d6b 0000  .B.... ^ap.pmk..
00000990: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 ffff 5901 9919  ........ ...Y...
000009a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000009b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000009c0: 0248 01ff ccf4 9df4 6170 2e70 6d6b 0000  .H......ap.pmk..
000009d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 0000 0100 ffff  ........ .......
000009e0: 0201 01ff 6e02 d833 6170 2e63 6861 6e00  ....n..3ap.chan.
000009f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 01ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000a00: 0201 01ff 557b 5978 6170 2e61 7574 686d  ....U{Yxap.authm
00000a10: 6f64 6500 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  ode.............
00000a20: 0201 01ff b83a 7e76 6170 2e68 6964 6465  .....:~vap.hidde
00000a30: 6e00 0000 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  n...............
00000a40: 0201 01ff f15a 1858 6170 2e6d 6178 2e63  .....Z.Xap.max.c
00000a50: 6f6e 6e00 0000 0000 04ff ffff ffff ffff  onn.............
00000a60: 0202 01ff 3d27 e857 6263 6e2e 696e 7465  ....='.Wbcn.inte
00000a70: 7276 616c 0000 0000 6400 ffff ffff ffff  rval....d.......
00000a80: 0201 01ff f16e 62b1 6170 2e70 6879 6d00  .....nb.ap.phym.
00000a90: 0000 0000 0000 0000 03ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000aa0: 0201 01ff 3f78 91cf 6170 2e70 6879 6277  ....?x..ap.phybw
00000ab0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 02ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000ac0: 0201 01ff 1696 af9c 6170 2e73 6e64 6368  ........ap.sndch
00000ad0: 616e 0000 0000 0000 01ff ffff ffff ffff  an..............
00000ae0: 0201 01ff fc04 cff4 6c6f 7261 7465 0000  ........lorate..
00000af0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000b00: 0242 0280 a5a5 f660 7374 612e 6d61 6300  .B.....`sta.mac.
00000b10: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff a681 622b  ..............b+
00000b20: 240a c414 b8b4 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  $...............
00000b30: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000b40: 0248 01ff 50f0 fb86 7374 612e 6d61 6300  .H..P...sta.mac.
00000b50: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0180 ffff  ................
00000b60: 0242 0280 0944 7ec8 6170 2e6d 6163 0000  .B...D~.ap.mac..
00000b70: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff 30b1 655c  ............0.e\
00000b80: 240a c414 b8b5 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  $...............
00000b90: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000ba0: 0248 01ff 4c38 1313 6170 2e6d 6163 0000  .H..L8..ap.mac..
00000bb0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0180 ffff  ................
00000bc0: 0001 01ff 477b 1363 7068 7900 0000 0000  ....G{.cphy.....
00000bd0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 03ff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00000be0: 0342 2100 0ec0 4c91 6361 6c5f 6461 7461  .B!...L.cal_data
00000bf0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0004 ffff 18cf 6acc  ..............j.
00000c00: 0610 0000 240a c414 b8b4 0000 6488 0000  ....$.......d...
00000c10: 0000 3000 494b 0000 6488 0000 8808 3000  ..0.IK..d.....0.
00000c20: 494b 0000 6488 0000 1111 3000 494b 0000  IK..d.....0.IK..
00000c30: 6488 0000 9919 3000 494b 0000 6488 0000  d.....0.IK..d...
00000c40: 2222 3000 494b 0000 6488 0000 ab2a 3000  ""0.IK..d....*0.
00000c50: 494b 0000 6488 0000 3333 3000 494b 0000  IK..d...330.IK..
00000c60: 6388 0000 bb3b 3000 484b 0000 6388 0000  c....;0.HK..c...
00000c70: 4444 3000 484b 0000 6388 0000 cd4c 3000  DD0.HK..c....L0.
00000c80: 484b 0000 6288 0000 5555 3000 484b 0000  HK..b...UU0.HK..
00000c90: 6288 0000 de5d 3000 484b 0000 6288 0000  b....]0.HK..b...
00000ca0: 6666 3000 484b 0000 6288 0000 ef6e 3000  ff0.HK..b....n0.
00000cb0: 484b 0000 6288 0000 7777 3000 484b 0000  HK..b...ww0.HK..
00000cc0: 6188 0000 0080 3000 484a 0000 6188 0000  a.....0.HJ..a...
00000cd0: 8888 3000 484a 0000 6188 0000 1191 3000  ..0.HJ..a.....0.
00000ce0: 484a 0000 6188 0000 9999 3000 484a 0000  HJ..a.....0.HJ..
00000cf0: 5f88 0000 22a2 3000 484a 0000 5f88 0000  _...".0.HJ.._...
00000d00: abaa 3000 484a 0000 5f88 0000 33b3 3000  ..0.HJ.._...3.0.
00000d10: 484a 0000 5f88 0000 bbbb 3000 484a 0000  HJ.._.....0.HJ..
00000d20: 5f88 0000 44c4 3000 484a 0000 5f88 0000  _...D.0.HJ.._...
00000d30: cdcc 3000 484a 0000 5e88 0000 55d5 3000  ..0.HJ..^...U.0.
00000d40: 484a 0000 5e88 0000 dedd 3000 484a 0000  HJ..^.....0.HJ..
00000d50: 5e88 0000 66e6 3000 484a 0000 5e88 0000  ^...f.0.HJ..^...
00000d60: efee 3000 484a 0000 5e88 0000 77f7 3000  ..0.HJ..^...w.0.
00000d70: 484a 0000 5d88 0000 0000 3100 484a 0000  HJ..].....1.HJ..
00000d80: 5d88 0000 8808 3100 484a 0000 5d88 0000  ].....1.HJ..]...
00000d90: 1111 3100 484a 0000 5c88 0000 9919 3100  ..1.HJ..\.....1.
00000da0: 484a 0000 5c88 0000 2222 3100 484a 0000  HJ..\...""1.HJ..
00000db0: 5c88 0000 ab2a 3100 484a 0000 5c88 0000  \....*1.HJ..\...
00000dc0: 3333 3100 484a 0000 5c88 0000 bb3b 3100  331.HJ..\....;1.
00000dd0: 484a 0000 5b88 0000 4444 3100 484a 0000  HJ..[...DD1.HJ..
00000de0: 5b88 0000 cd4c 3100 484a 0000 5b88 0000  [....L1.HJ..[...
00000df0: 5555 3100 484a 0000 5b88 0000 de5d 3100  UU1.HJ..[....]1.
00000e00: 484a 0000 5a88 0000 6666 3100 484a 0000  HJ..Z...ff1.HJ..
00000e10: 5a88 0000 ef6e 3100 484a 0000 5a88 0000  Z....n1.HJ..Z...
00000e20: 7777 3100 484a 0000 5a88 0000 0080 3100  ww1.HJ..Z.....1.
00000e30: 484a 0000 5a88 0000 8888 3100 484a 0000  HJ..Z.....1.HJ..
00000e40: 5988 0000 1191 3100 474a 0000 5988 0000  Y.....1.GJ..Y...
00000e50: 9999 3100 474a 0000 5988 0000 22a2 3100  ..1.GJ..Y...".1.
00000e60: 474a 0000 5988 0000 abaa 3100 474a 0000  GJ..Y.....1.GJ..
00000e70: 5788 0000 33b3 3100 4749 0000 5788 0000  W...3.1.GI..W...
00000e80: bbbb 3100 4749 0000 5788 0000 44c4 3100  ..1.GI..W...D.1.
00000e90: 4749 0000 5788 0000 cdcc 3100 4749 0000  GI..W.....1.GI..
00000ea0: 5688 0000 55d5 3100 4749 0000 5688 0000  V...U.1.GI..V...
00000eb0: dedd 3100 4749 0000 5688 0000 66e6 3100  ..1.GI..V...f.1.
00000ec0: 4749 0000 5688 0000 efee 3100 4749 0000  GI..V.....1.GI..
00000ed0: 5688 0000 77f7 3100 4749 0000 5588 0000  V...w.1.GI..U...
00000ee0: 0000 3200 4749 0000 5588 0000 8808 3200  ..2.GI..U.....2.
00000ef0: 4749 0000 5588 0000 1111 3200 4749 0000  GI..U.....2.GI..
00000f00: 5588 0000 9919 3200 4749 0000 5388 0000  U.....2.GI..S...
00000f10: 2222 3200 4749 0000 5388 0000 ab2a 3200  ""2.GI..S....*2.
00000f20: 4749 0000 5388 0000 3333 3200 4749 0000  GI..S...332.GI..
00000f30: 5388 0000 bb3b 3200 4749 0000 5388 0000  S....;2.GI..S...
00000f40: 4444 3200 4749 0000 5388 0000 cd4c 3200  DD2.GI..S....L2.
00000f50: 4749 0000 5388 0000 5555 3200 4749 0000  GI..S...UU2.GI..
00000f60: 5388 0000 de5d 3200 4749 0000 5288 0000  S....]2.GI..R...
00000f70: 6666 3200 4749 0000 5288 0000 ef6e 3200  ff2.GI..R....n2.
00000f80: 4749 0000 5288 0000 7777 3200 4749 0000  GI..R...ww2.GI..
00000f90: 5288 0000 0080 3200 4749 0000 5288 0000  R.....2.GI..R...
00000fa0: 8888 3200 4749 0000 5188 0000 1191 3200  ..2.GI..Q.....2.
00000fb0: 4749 0000 5188 0000 9999 3200 4749 0000  GI..Q.....2.GI..
00000fc0: 5188 0000 22a2 3200 4749 0000 5188 0000  Q...".2.GI..Q...
00000fd0: abaa 3200 4749 0000 4f88 0000 33b3 3200  ..2.GI..O...3.2.
00000fe0: 4648 0000 4f88 0000 bbbb 3200 4648 0000  FH..O.....2.FH..
00000ff0: 4f88 0000 44c4 3200 4648 0000 4f88 0000  O...D.2.FH..O...
00001000: feff ffff 0100 0000 feff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00001010: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff a348 9f38  .............H.8
00001020: aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa faff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00001030: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00001040: 0342 1d01 23fd a9bb 6361 6c5f 6461 7461  .B..#...cal_data
00001050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 7003 ffff 3650 2b44  ........p...6P+D
00001060: cdcc 3200 4648 0000 0000 0000 f8ff ff00  ..2.FH..........
00001070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0901 0001 0001 0101  ................
00001080: 0801 0201 0101 ff00 0501 0101 0001 ff00  ................
00001090: 0301 0001 0301 0001 0301 0001 fe00 ff00  ................
000010a0: 3900 f907 0300 c507 c507 4607 0f07 030f  9.........F.....
000010b0: 0703 0f07 030f 0703 b707 94fe 250b 0000  ............%...
000010c0: 4343 1717 5757 4e48 423c 3834 f5fe 040a  CC..WWNHB<84....
000010d0: 0e11 f6ff 050b 0f13 f7fe 040b 0f13 f7fe  ................
000010e0: 040b 0f13 7070 7172 7379 777b 001a 0e18  ....ppqrsyw{....
000010f0: 1814 1a14 1600 2c00 ff00 0101 0000 f907  ......,.........
00001100: b907 b907 1001 ff00 ff00 fe00 0701 fd00  ................
00001110: fe00 ff00 0201 fc00 ff00 fe00 513e 94fe  ............Q>..
00001120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 7f00 2001 7b00 100d  .......... .{...
00001130: 0000 0100 0200 0300 0400 0004 0104 0204  ................
00001140: 0304 0404 0504 0804 0904 0a04 0030 0130  .............0.0
00001150: 0230 0330 0430 0530 0034 0134 0234 0334  .0.0.0.0.4.4.4.4
00001160: 0434 0038 0138 0238 0040 0140 0240 0340  .4.8.8.8.@.@.@.@
00001170: 0440 0540 0044 0144 0244 0344 0444 0048  .@.@.D.D.D.D.D.H
00001180: 0148 0248 0348 0448 0548 0848 0948 0a48  .H.H.H.H.H.H.H.H
00001190: 0b48 0c48 0d48 1848 1948 1a48 1b48 1c48  .H.H.H.H.H.H.H.H
000011a0: 1d48 3848 3948 3a48 3b48 3c48 3d48 0000  .H8H9H:H;H<H=H..
000011b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100  ................
000011c0: 0200 0300 0400 0004 0104 0204 0304 0404  ................
000011d0: 0504 0804 0904 0a04 0030 0130 0230 0330  .........0.0.0.0
000011e0: 0430 0530 0034 0134 0234 0334 0434 0038  .0.0.4.4.4.4.4.8
000011f0: 0138 0238 0040 0140 0240 0340 0440 0540  .8.8.@.@.@.@.@.@
00001200: 0044 0144 0244 0344 0444 0048 0148 0248  .D.D.D.D.D.H.H.H
00001210: 0348 0050 0150 0250 0350 0450 0550 0054  .H.P.P.P.P.P.P.T
00001220: 0154 0254 0354 0058 0158 0258 0358 0458  .T.T.T.X.X.X.X.X
00001230: 005c 015c 025c 035c 045c 055c 085c 095c  .\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\
00001240: 0a5c 0b5c 0c5c 0d5c 185c 195c 1a5c 1b5c  .\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\
00001250: 1c5c 1d5c 385c 395c 3a5c 3b5c 3c5c 3d5c  .\.\8\9\:\;\<\=\
00001260: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001270: d800 eb00 d000 e200 d200 e600 d100 e300  ................
00001280: d100 df00 d400 e600 d200 e500 d200 dd00  ................
00001290: f300 fa00 f300 fa00 f300 fa00 f300 fa00  ................
000012a0: f300 f700 f300 f700 f300 f700 f300 f700  ................
000012b0: f300 fa00 f300 fa00 f300 fa00 f300 f500  ................
000012c0: f300 f500 f300 f500 f300 f500 f700 f300  ................
000012d0: f700 f300 f400 f300 f400 f300 f400 f300  ................
000012e0: f400 f300 f400 f300 f400 f300 f400 f300  ................
000012f0: ec00 f300 e700 0001 e700 0001 e700 0001  ................
00001300: e500 0001 e500 0001 e500 0001 7158 2abd  ............qX*.
00001310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001330: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001340: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001350: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001370: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000013a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000013b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000013c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000013d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000013e0: 0348 01ff d2a2 cfb8 6361 6c5f 6461 7461  .H......cal_data
000013f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 7007 0000 0200 ffff  ........p.......
00001400: 0342 0200 a6f3 826c 6361 6c5f 6d61 6300  .B.....lcal_mac.
00001410: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 ffff a681 622b  ..............b+
00001420: 240a c414 b8b4 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  $...............
00001430: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00001440: 0348 01ff 608c 90c6 6361 6c5f 6d61 6300  .H..`...cal_mac.
00001450: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0100 ffff  ................
00001460: 0304 01ff 32ce c600 6361 6c5f 7665 7273  ....2...cal_vers
00001470: 696f 6e00 0000 0000 0610 0000 ffff ffff  ion.............
00001480: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
00001490: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014e0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000014f0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
<snip>
00003ff0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
```